# How do I separate a mysql datestamp field into year, quarter, month and day

Tags: mysql, sorting, datestamp

I have a mysql database with a datestamp field for entries. I'd really like to separate out the year, quarter, month and day into individual columns. I can make the new columns without a problem but I don't know how to write a query that does this easily. I've been playing around with things like this

```
SELECT MONTH();
FROM `datestamp`
```

But haven't had any joy...

Any help gratefully received :-)

Comment: is your table called datestamp, or is that a column in your table?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

```
SELECT DAY(`datestamp`) AS `day`,
       MONTH(`datestamp`) AS `month`,
       YEAR(`datestamp`) AS `year`,
       QUARTER(`datestamp`) AS `quarter`
  FROM `table`;
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what did it... 'UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Year` = YEAR(datestamp);
UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Quarter` = QUARTER(datestamp);
UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Month` = MONTH(datestamp);
UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Date` = DAYOFMONTH(datestamp);'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT MONTH(`datestamp`) AS `datemonth`, 
DAY(`datestamp`) AS `dateday`,
YEAR(`datestamp`) AS `dateyear`,
QUARTER(`datestamp`) AS `datequarter`
FROM `table`;
```

Comment: Thank you,this is what did it... 'UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Year` = YEAR(datestamp);
UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Quarter` = QUARTER(datestamp);
UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Month` = MONTH(datestamp);
UPDATE `fourg124_lime2`.`lime_survey_81823` SET `Date` = DAYOFMONTH(datestamp);'